# Need to encrypt the data in teradata SQL Query

Tags: teradata

I have requirement to encrypt the data in teradata using SQL Query or Stored procedure.
I have data in below sample:

```
May123@34@#
AbC@#$%1234DE#f
zyx@12
```

So I want output in the below format

```
aaadddpddpp
aaappppddddaapa
aaapdd
```

So we want to replace character with a and number with d and special character with p.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: For a basic algorithm such as that, you can use REGEXP_REPLACE but how do you decode it back to what it was originally? If you are seeking a proper enterprise solution, you are looking at a third-party offering that can do encryption and/or tokenization of the data. The Teradata client can encrypt data in-flight between the database and client. Additionally, certain platforms can encrypt the data on the disk at rest. Finally, you may be able to implement your own UDFs to decode and encode the data. It’s a question whose answer can go in many directions and you need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like data masking, not encryption. Encryption is something you can undo with decryption where masking is a one-way thing.

You can use `Regexp_Replace()` to do the swaps:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('May123@34@#', '[a-z]', 'a', 1, 0, 'i'),'[0-9]', 'd', 1, 0, 'i'), '[^a-z]', 'p', 1, 0, 'i')
```

result:

```
aaadddpddpp
```

This first swaps all letters to `a`. Then it swaps all numbers to `d`. Finally anything left over is swapped to `p`.