# How can I anonymise rows in a table using Teradata sql?

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to write a query in Teradata SQL that extracts employee information. Since the data contains personally identifiable information I'd like to anonymise the identity fields (employee_id and employee_name).

So far I have this query, where I select the employee_id, employee_name, date_col and some other columns where the date column satisfies some condition. I then concatenate the employee_id and employee_name into a single column.

```
SELECT (employee_id || employee_name)(TITLE 'unique_id'), date_col, some_other_cols
FROM employee_database
WHERE employee_database.date_col > date '2015-01-01'
```

I then want to perform an anonymisation step on the concatenated unique_id column. I know that Teradata has a HASH keyword but I can't seem to get it to work on a column.

This table can contain rows where the unique_id is repeated (it is a table of sick absence so an employee can be off sick more than once) so the hashed version of the unique_id needs to reflect this.

Comment: It sounds like you want to mask data?  Lots of answers on SO for that - [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56025257/2751573)

Comment: The function is called HASHROW and returns a BYTE(4): `HASHROW(employee_id ,employee_name)`

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for this. I didn't know that the technique is called masking. Now I know what I'm looking for I should be able to figure it out. Thanks again for the pointer!